# Refreshing an OAuth access token for Microsoft Live API

Tags: rest, oauth, access-token, microsoft-live-connect

Currently, I'm having the user log in to Microsoft Live by sending a request in a web view to the following URL:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&scope=[SCOPES]&response_type=token&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&display=popup
```

This works perfectly, and I receive and save the `access_token` and `authentication_token`. Note that it doesn't return a `refresh_token`, even if I include the `wl.offline_access` scope.

The problem occurs when the access token expires and needs to be refreshed. I'm attempting to refresh the token using a method from [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx#flows):

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET]&refresh_token=[WHAT TO PUT HERE?]&grant_type=refresh_token
```

However, a `refresh_token` was never returned in the login, so I'm not sure what to pass in. Note that sending the `authentication_token` (what is it supposed to be used for?) as the `refresh_token` parameter results in the following:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "The provided value for the input parameter 'refresh_token' is not valid."
}
```

Does anyone know how to properly refresh a Microsoft Live token through their REST API?

Comment: did you figure it out how to get the refresh token?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After further reading through Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx#authcodegrant) and experimenting, I was able to figure out how to do this.

The problem with my initial attempt was that I was requesting the `wl.offline_access` scope while using the [implicit grant flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx#flows), as their documentation says not to:

> Note  Do not include the `wl.offline_access` scope if you're using the
>   implicit grant flow (`response_type=token`).

So, I changed my URL to the following (using the [authorization code grant flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx#authcodegrant) since I need offline access):

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&scope=[SCOPES]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&display=popup
```

Then, once I received the `code` in the callback, I called the following endpoint to retrieve the access and refresh tokens:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET]&code=[CODE FROM AUTHORIZATION]&grant_type=authorization_code
```

**NOTE: Microsoft's documentation is *INCORRECT* for this endpoint in the above links. This is a `GET` request, NOT a `POST` request as their documentation claims.**

This method *finally* returned the `access_token` and `refresh_token` parameters, and I was able to use both as expected.

Comment: So what is the url you used to call data from one drive. I used
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive with Authorization: bearer {token}. But it returns "Authentication failed"

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I do get request I get this error:  "error_description": "The provided request must have content-type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."

Comment: Sounds like you should probably set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as your `Content-Type` header then @user2924482 :)